# Make iAd correct for the Submit for the AppStore

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, app-store, iad

I develop a SpriteKit Game for the AppStore and I add iAd to the App but when I run the App the iAd sometimes close and open again. Is it correct for the Submit for the AppStore or did I have to change something in the code.

```
var UIiAd: ADBannerView = ADBannerView()

var SH = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
var BV: CGFloat = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}

// 1
func appdelegate() -> AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
}

// 2
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    print("Showing ad")
    BV = UIiAd.bounds.height

    UIiAd.delegate = self
    UIiAd = self.appdelegate().UIiAd
    UIiAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, SH - BV, 0, 0)
    self.view.addSubview(UIiAd)


    self.view.addSubview(UIiAd)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    UIiAd.delegate = nil
    UIiAd.removeFromSuperview()
}

// 4
func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    print("ad loaded")
    UIiAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, SH + 50, 0, 0)

    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1)
    UIiAd.alpha = 1
    UIiAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, SH - 50, 0, 0)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}

// 5
func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    print("failed to receive ad")
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0)
    UIiAd.alpha = 1
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

Comment: It already happened to me. You should not be worrying about this. They might disappear for a second and appear again.

Answer (score 0):

It is OK. Depending on the availability of a (new) ad iAd will hide the banner view.